# How to change mode-map of the minor mode?

Tags: keymap, minor-mode

I would like to change the mode-map of a minor mode with mode map.

I mean replacing the original mode-map that was specified in the `define-minor-mode` call with another one. Keeping the two mode-map unmodified.

How could I do that?

Comment: Please, give more information. Which minor mode do you want to modify? Which keymap do you want to use? Do you want to set the keymap of an existing minor mode to the keymap of another one or do you define your own minor-mode? When you define your own minor mode you can pass the keymap to `define-minor-mode`. Otherwise you can also use `copy-keymap`.

Comment: What @Tobias said. The question is not very clear. You have `set-keymap-parent` and `copy-keymap` as two possibilities for grabbing stuff from another keymap. What you do depends on what you really want/need, which is not yet clear from your question.

Comment: Made the question more clear I want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

After digging a bit I found the `minor-mode-map-alist` variable in [the doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keymaps-and-Minor-Modes.html). It is holding a mapping between the minor modes symbol, and their associated mode-map.

Hence to replace the mode-map of `'my-minor-mode` I went for:

```
(setcdr (assoc 'my-minor-mode minor-mode-map-alist) my-minor-mode-map))
```

Comment: That solution looks rather hacky. I am still wondering whether you actually should define a new minor-mode with `(define-minor-mode new-minor-mode "some doc" nil nil my-minor-mode-map (other-minor-mode (if new-minor-mode 1 -1)))` and use that new minor mode instead of the other one.