# Add a keymap to a minor mode

Tags: keymap, minor-mode

The minor-mode `show-paren-mode` does not have a keymap. Is there a way to add such a keymap so that I can define some key-bindings that depend on this minor mode?

I saw a solution [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35661/how-to-change-mode-map-of-the-minor-mode) which involves modifying `minor-mode-map-alist`, with a comment saying that the solution is "rather hacky". Is there a better solution in my case?

Comment: there are a couple of ways to do that, what do you want to do? show-paren-mode has no more interactive functionality than (de)active it .

Comment: I just want to assign a particular functionality to a key when `show-paren-mode` is active. I don't understand the second part of your answer.

Comment: Rather than hacking on `minor-mode-map-alist` which probably will bite back more often than not, I'd write my own minor mode with the keybindings I'd like just cheking if `show-parens-mode` is active.

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't this also mean that I have to enable my minor mode when `show-paren-mode` is enabled by adding a hook? In any case, defining a minor mode for just a a single key-binding seem to me an overkill. Is there a way to "apply"/"remove" a keymap in `show-paren-mode-hook`?

Comment: you could, if it exists. Or you could add a keybinding to `prog-mode-map` or whatever relevant mode which will cover your use case for `show-paren-mode`.